# AlarmManager - repetition pattern

Tags: android, android-alarms

I want to set an alarm thats repeating in different ways, for example, every day, every week, every other week, on weekdays, on weekends, etc..
The problem is with weekdays and weekends. I know that for example Vibrator has an option to set repetition pattern, so i was wondering if AlarmManager has it too? I couldn't find anything on this. Obviously, i can calculate times myself and set every day repeating alarm 5 times for weekdays, and 2 times for weekends, but I'm wondering if there's a better way i didn't find? 
Thanks :)

Comment: i had the same issue, i solved it by calculating the interval by myself and then using an repeating alarm and passing the interval to the alarmmanager, i also did not find any patterns for the alarmmanager

Comment: yeah thats what i was planning to do, but i thought there might be a smarter way :)

Comment: i found out that my repetation code doesnt work, it pops on different times, android does something weird

Comment: Be careful with time calculations - time zones, seconds, milliseconds.. That might be a problem

Comment: I had to trigger an event every week but it is calling it every third or second day : ) i don't think that i did it wrong ; )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here's how i solved it in the end. time12 is the time the user set, and the alarms are popping either on weekdays or on weekends at the time the user set.

```
//6-Weekdays
case 6:
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTimeInMillis(time12);
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 6 && cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != 7)
         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time12,1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,        operationBroadcast);
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);
    }
 break;

//7-Weekends
case 7:
 Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal2.setTimeInMillis(time12);
 for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    if (cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 6 ||cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == 7)
         alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time12, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, operationBroadcast);
    cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);
    }
 break;
```